# Linq - how to convert this code to linq

Tags: linq

My Linq-fu is not good enough to translate the following into hopefully one or two lines.

```
 var errors = new List<string>();
 foreach (var key in ModelState.Keys)
 {
   errors.Add(ModelState[key].Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage);
 }

 return Json(new { success = false, errors = errors });
```

Comment: There's no point in `OrDefault`; it'll fail anyway.

Comment: If you're having trouble "LINQifying" this, you seriously need to learn more LINQ. I recommend you read the [Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) articles. Additionally, like SLaks said, FirstOrDefault is worse than First here, because `First` fails with a meaningful exception, but with FirstOrDefault this will fail with a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @Martinho: Fair enough...but to be fair though, it is how Scott Hanselmann posted this code I was just trying to improve it a bit... http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx. We can't all be experts at everything...I am sure I can run circles around some of your other skillsets :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact translation would be:

```
var errors = ModelState.Keys.Select(k => ModelState[k].Errors.First().ErrorMessage);
return Json(new { success = false, errors = errors.ToList() });
```

Provided ModelState is a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` or similar, you could use the values directly:

```
var errors = ModelState.Values.Select(v => v.Errors.First().ErrorMessage);
return Json(new { success = false, errors = errors.ToList() });
```

Comment: perfect, thx. It is MVC's modelstate object. I was close in my tries, but wasn't sure how to select the key. Makes sense, thx.

Answer (score 3):

The closes translation (which is unsafe because FirstOrDefault() could return null in which case your code would throw a null reference exception) would be:

```
return Json(new { success = false,
                  errors = ModelState.Values
                      .Select(ms => ms.Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage)
                      .ToList() });
```

You could make it a bit safer using:

```
return Json(new { 
    success = false,
    errors =
        ModelState.Values
                  .Select(ms => 
                          { 
                              var error = ms.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
                              return error == null ? error.ErrorMessage : "";
                          })
                  .ToList() });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return new Json(new 
   {
      success = false,
      errors = ModelState.Keys.Select(k => ModelState[key].Errors.First().ErrorMessage).ToList()
   });
```